# Should A Manager discuss hiring plans with his/her team?

Tags: work-environment, hiring-process, new-job, manager, hiring

I have been working for a company for about 8 years with three people in the team including the manager. My colleague and I have same level of responsibilities. Our workload has increased tremendously in the past couple of years. I discussed the situation with my manager few times, to which the manager states, "We'll see what can be done".

I heard via grapevine within the company about three months ago that my manager will be hiring.  I did not ask the manager anything regarding this unofficial information.  Days ago, there is an internal job posting for my department; the job description and requirements match my current duties with the exception of "Senior" added to the job title and the salary level a bit higher than my level. The position is permanent as well.

My concerns: My manager did not discuss his plan of the new position or his expectations/visions about the department with the team. All I thought we need is a new person to augment the team and assist in offsetting the workload going forward. To me, the situation looks like a promotion or reorganization in the department. If this is so, I do not think it requires posting the job. It should have been an internal/departmental discussion, move up or promote one of us who are current staff, and do a job posting for a third or new person to offset the workload.

I am interested in the new position; it involves what I am currently doing and pays more.  The fact that the manager is silent about it, and did not have discussion with the team gives me a concern. I'm convinced there is something fishy going on, or maybe not.  Your thought?

Comment: Have you tried talking to your boss about this new posting? Maybe not informing you was an oversight by him. If you are piled on with workload chances are he is as well.

Answer (score 9):

First, apply for the position.  If it's effectively a promotion, then apply.  Maybe he's looking for you to take some initiative?

Second, if you're "counselled" that you should not have applied for the position, it seems pretty clear that your manager, for whatever reason, has decided he needs a stronger leader in your team.  I can't tell you if he's right or not, but that would be my impression of the events you laid out.

If you are selected for this new position, then your first order of business is clear:  Hire to backfill your role.  It wouldn't hurt to start researching that, right now.  As in this moment.  If you walk in to your manager for the "interview" of this promotion with an effective plan on how you're going to fill your existing position, that would be a strong indicator that you are a leader.

To this end, see if you can find out from HR what the internal hiring process is?  Do you have to post a job internally for a certain length of time before posting externally?  (Some companies have this rule.)  Don't work above your pay grade, but learn all you can about what your new responsibilities would be and how to execute them.

If you don't get the position, and instead have someone hired in above you, then you and your manager probably have different perceptions about your abilities.  You either change you (Learn more), change your communication with your manager (show you can do more), or change your manager (find another job).

Comment: Agree apply.  It is unfortunate this was not discussed up front but still no reason not to apply.